# EXPORTING EVERNOTE INTO EXCEL-columns for Name, Date Created, Tags, Notebook, etc

Tags: export, evernote

I'd like to export my Evernote account into an .xls or .csv file that contains Title, Date Created/Updated, text of the note, and tags (separated by commas or in individual columns).

I'm not a programmer. I'm trying to join data contained in Excel to the tags I've created in the Evernote database-I could manually go through and add the tags but I have thousands of notes and I'm sure there's a way to export this in bulk. Anyone have ideas?

Comment: Stack Overflow is primarily for questions specifically about programming, so you'll probably find a better answer somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Evernote notes can contain attachments (PDFs, images, word documents, etc.) as well as contain a massive amount of text the contents of which would not fit in a standard excel cell and could cause issues with csv parsers.  As such Evernote notes cannot easily be exported as a xls or csv file.  Evernote recommends you export notes in their format (.enex) or as a HTML file.  The Evernote clients for Mac and Windows can export all notes (or any subset of your notes as you chose) as enex or html files.

Sources:

```
https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/3416-evernote-csv-exports/
https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/39135-export-contacts-to-a-csvexcel-file/
https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/33333-export-my-notes-files-linux/
```